# Extract all items from a combobox in a website and paste into excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract all the items from a dropdown list on a website and paste it into an excel sheet columnwise..

I'm guessing getElementById should work.. Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks.

Below is the html code from the debugger..
The list keeps getting updated, so I need to fetch this updated list into excel column every time I need to generate company-wise reports.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML>
<HEAD>
    <title>BBP::Reports</title>
    <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
    <meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
    <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
    <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" 
name="vs_targetSchema">
    <LINK href="Styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</HEAD>
<body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
    <form method="post" action="./advrep_n.aspx" id="Form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" 
 />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" 



value="/wEPDwUJODc1NTQzNzM4DjB/b4C3EeltFSjXjpspkhpCg==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" 
value="3479CCB4" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" 


value="/wEdAMcCytJuOAwHIV9g5j76SLhgqMo8=" />
</div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search" 
id="btnsearch" 
title="Click here to search" 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#D83D54&#39;" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=&#39;#616161&#39;" 
style="color:White;background-color:#616161;font- 
family:Arial;height:25px;width:87px;Z-INDEX: 120; LEFT: 832px; POSITION: 
absolute; TOP: 78px" />



        <span id="Label5" style="display:inline- 
block;color:White;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Arial;font- 
size:Large;font-weight:bold;height:28px;width:288px;Z-INDEX: 147; LEFT: 
663px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: -1px"><p align="center"> Behavior Based 
Process</span>
        <select name="ddlCategory" id="ddlCategory" tabindex="1" 
style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;height:55px;width:231px;Z-INDEX: 
154; LEFT: 578px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 73px">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Project">Project</option>
<option value="Maintenance">Maintenance</option>
<option value="Operations">Operations</option>
<option value="Shutdown">Shutdown</option>



 </select><span id="Label7" style="display:inline-block;background- 
 color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font- 
 size:8pt;height:6px;width:34px;Z-INDEX: 112; LEFT: 190px; POSITION: 
absolute; TOP: 160px">Task:</span><select name="ddlCompany" 
id="ddlCompany" tabindex="1" style="font-family:Verdana;font- 
size:8pt;height:55px;width:230px;Z-INDEX: 115; LEFT: 578px; POSITION: 
absolute; TOP: 136px">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Acuren">Acuren</option>
<option value="Ahmadiah">Ahmadiah</option>
<option value="Al Bahar">Al Bahar</option>
<option value="Al Mussairie">Al Mussairie</option>
<option value="Al Subol">Al Subol</option>
<option value="Al-Barrak">Al-Barrak</option>
<option value="Al-Eisa">Al-Eisa</option>
<option value="Al-Julaih">Al-Julaih</option>
<option value="Al-Khadda">Al-Khadda</option>
<option value="Al-Kulaib">Al-Kulaib</option>
<option value="Al-Saqabi">Al-Saqabi</option>
<option value="Al-Zahim">Al-Zahim</option>
<option value="ALESSA">ALESSA</option>
<option value="Alghanim">Alghanim</option>
<option value="Alliance">Alliance</option>
<option value="ALMEER">ALMEER</option>
```

Comment: Have you tried any code ? If yes can you paste it.

Comment: It might be easier to get values from original source, how do you update this website list?

Comment: website is managed by some other department.. we do not have access to it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) id selector to get the parent `select` element then add a descendant combinator and `option` type selector to get the child `option` tags within the parent `select`. CSS selectors are applied via querySelector (Single match), or `querySelectorAll` to get all matches. You can then loop the nodeList returned and store the value attributes into an array and write that array out once to sheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As Object, options As Object, output(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"
        While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set options = .document.querySelectorAll("#ddlCompany option")
        ReDim output(1 To options.Length - 1)
        For i = 1 To options.Length - 1          'ignore first empty value
            output(i) = options.Item(i).Value
        Next
    End With
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(output), 1) = Application.Transpose(output)
End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply.. I'm getting an error at the following line.. 
    ReDim output(1 To options.Length - 1)  
Error 9: subscript out of range  
Any idea why?

Comment: What is the value of options.Length ?

Comment: its around 152 now.. but it may increase / decrease as they keep adding and deleting contractors

Comment: that is the length of the variable options?

Comment: sorry, may be i didn't quite understand your question. I'm not very technical about this stuff. I'm sorry, again, could you please re-phrase it for me in an easy way?

Comment: what i meant by 152 is the number of items currently present in the drop down selector.. first one is blank..

Comment: If you step through my code by pressing F8 - code will execute line by line. When you get to the line that fails press ctrl + g and in the immediate window that opens enter ?options.length then press enter

Comment: runtime error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Comment: ok that was when i closed the ie window.. if i dont close the ie window, then it shows error: Object required

Comment: Which line does error occur on?    1) If you pause before the line  Set options = .document.querySelectorAll("#ddlCompany option")  when pressing F8  then move to the next line does this make a difference? 2) Is the target element inside a parent iframe/frame tag?

Comment: pressing f8 doesn't do anything on my computer.. instead when i run using f5 i get a debug option.. when i click debug it shows the line "ReDim output(1 To options.Length - 1) " highlighted.. error says subscript out of range

Comment: and also, i had to change .document.querySelectorAll("#ddlCompany option") to .document.querySelectorAll("ddlCompany")

Comment: and the error occurs exactly when the line ReDim output(1 To options.Length - 1) is highlighted and when i press f8 on that line.. then i press debug.. and then ctrl+g.. and then ?options.length.. and it returns 0

Comment: i changed it back to what you suggested initially, .document.querySelectorAll("#ddlCompany option") and still it's the same.. and options.length is 0

Comment: any idea how i should go about this?

Comment: Can you share more of the html please? Especially the bit just before where you currently show. I would like to see from  the <select> opening tag and not just from the </select> closing.

Comment: i have updated the html code like you said.. could you please have a look at it?

Comment: step through the code line by line with F8 and check again with a slight pause before  .document.querySelectorAll("#ddlCompany option")  . It is correct for the html you show.

Comment: i'm getting options.length as 0

Comment: It got it to work finally!! Had to make a minor change: Set options = .document.getElementById("ddlCompany") and it worked like a charm!!! Thanks man! You're a genius! thank you so much for being so impossibly patient and understanding.. Peace!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML code from the website it is tricky to give a definite answer, but yes, you'd want to start with a getElementsById call if the dropdown is given an id. I've pasted in the example W3Schools suggests to create dropdowns but there are other ways. (I added in an id.)

If you get a result, so you have the node where the id is, you can loop through the ChildNodes object which is one of its properties, and then inspect each child's properties. Experiment with getting the ones you want and put them into Excel cells, and configure depending on your design.

Use the documentation to check both the attributes and the inner text of each child.

```
<select id="CarMakes" name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```